# NSCollectionView - how to make it scroll more smoothly?

Tags: nsscrollview, nscollectionview

I have an `NSCollectionView` in an `NSCollectionViewGridLayout` with possibly 100s of items in it.

This leads to the unpleasant effect that scrolling the view looks twitchy (jerky). And that's on the fastest Mac currently available (Geekbench score over 6500).

When I try the same in Finder, with its Icon View, and a similar amount of items of equal size, it scrolls much less twitchy.

How can I make the scrolling smoother?

I have reduced the setup code in `collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:` to the bare minimum (i.e. I just return the result from `makeItemWithIdentifier:`), yet it still does not scroll as smoothly as the Finder.

The `NSCollectionViewItem`'s view is loaded from a nib file and contains an `NSImageView` and two `NSTextView`s, which is also quite similar to the Finder's Icon view.

I guess part of the problem is that when I scroll, the framework wants to reload the entire view before it considers to look at the scrollbar handle's drag movement again. So, while the user holds and moves the handle of the scrollbar, **the view prepares every item of the last scrollbar position even though the user may have already moved the scrollbar handle further to a point where none of the now-preparing items are visible in the view any more**.

So, I wonder if there is a way to detect that the scrollbar is already going further so that I could somehow abort the creation of items that won't be visible, so that the scrollbar's handle can move faster?

Comment: I am in a similar situation. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @francisfeng any luck solving this issue? Found myself in the similar situation...